# XSLT replace character in function transform XML data

Tags: xml, xslt

Part Input XML

```
<Attribute name="Napięcie wyjściowe (max)"><Values><Value Name="12 V" /></Values></Attribute>
```

I cannot transform this via XSLT because I get `Invalid element name`

because this code should try get output somelike:

```
<napiecie_wyjsciowe_(max)>12 V</napiecie_wyjsciowe_(max)>
```

This is part code transform XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="Attribute">
  <xsl:element name="{translate(@name,' ','_')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value/@Name"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

how to add to this code for replace characters like `()` in elements `<Attribute name="Napięcie wyjściowe (max)">`

Comment: With `translate`, you can remove e.g. `(` and ')` by having `' ()', '_'` as the second and third argument or you can replace them as well with e.g. `' ()', '___'`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen im not sure I correct do it ?     <xsl:template match="Attribute">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(@name,' ()', '_')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value/@Name"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: Which character do you want to use as a replacement for `(`, which one for `)`? Put them at the same position in the third argument to `translate` these characters have in the second argument string.